# Inject properties with @Named

Tags: spring

I have a project that has to be compatible with Spring and Guice. So far it is good.

In Guice, properties are injected using the `@Named` annotation, where as it is customary to use the proprietary `@Value` annotation in Spring.

How can I inject the key/value pairs of a `.properties` file using the `@Named` annotation in Spring?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can't. Also since Spring 3.0 @Named has a different meaning than the one you expect. @Named is the replacement of @Component to support the standard JSR 330. See here:

[Spring 3 And JSR-330 @Inject And @Named Example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-3-and-jsr-330-inject-and-named-example/)